# Java: If I got stuck while programming, how do I know where to look in the documentation?

Tags: java, documentation

Here's a real life example I had experienced before, and this is something that makes me ponder and question this mystery.

**Before:** I have no idea how to instantiate a class dynamically just by using the name of the class.

**After:** I looked around in someone else's Java source code, being determined to look for something unrelated to the above, like how to do collision detection, and just accidentally came across a piece of code that answers correctly my question of how to instantiate a class dynamically.

The piece of code in question is this:

```
A a = (A) Class.forName("A").newInstance();
```

Where `A` is the name of a Java source file, `A.java`.

From here, I was not only intrigued about it, but also starting to wonder, how a Java programmer learn all of this if they were given only the Java language documentation.

How do they know where to look for in the documentation, if they are practicing Java language?
I know that novice Java programmers get some experiences from expert Java programmers, but where do the expert Java programmers learn all of this, if they **at first** don't know where to look for in the documentation?

Or do they just read from page 1 to the end of the documentation, and follow along closely as much as possible, and start from there? That would take a long time to finish, and it would be an impressive feat to do.

Comment: This really isn't a question suited for SO as it isn't constructive. That being said, most people buy a book. Or read the Tutorials available from Oracle; they're quite good.

Comment: The API is pretty big; "reading" it, while occasionally interesting, isn't necessarily the best use of your time. Reading things like the Core Java books, practice tests for certs, tutorials, searching the web for "create java class from string" etc. all help. In this case I might have looked for a `Class` class to see if it could help.

Comment: Google. The class will be yours (or your coworkers), from the JRE (`java.` or `javax.`) -search the Java API Javadoc- or from a third party library (locate provider, search for javadoc within the jars provided or in internet.

Comment: The question remains. How do you know you have to find `Class`, if you don't know what to look for in the first place? There's got to be a hint somewhere in the documentation that tells you `Class` is more suited to one's need, but only if you know what you are to find. I only give out an example of `Class`. There could be other stuffs in the documentation that I did not know of in the first place, and probably will never know about it unless I came upon it by chance.

Comment: Just to add some more details about books and/or tutorial. I have yet to find an example in my book telling me about classes I probably will never use in the lifetime of Java programming.

Comment: Fair warning: the technique you've just learned (`Class.newInstance()`) isn't very good for general use, as it's fragile, slightly hacky, and assumes that the class actually has a default constructor.  You're better off passing around explicit factory objects, as far as maintainability goes.

Comment: Most of the time the process is really simple: 1. google for salient terms in the description of your problem; 2. follow the first hit to an SO question that discusses your problem.

Comment: I like this question, as it's really asking, "how do I find fishing lessons instead of asking for fish?". SO needs more OPs like this OP!

Comment: In fact, I agree that this question is off-topic for SO, but I couldn't bring myself to vote for the close because it's a refreshing question. Is there a place where the OP can ask it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you search google for the Java docs... that send you to the Oracle website that contains it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

On some cases only the API is necessary, but when you need a full formed example you could search for code samples or snippets, or the problem you want to solve itself (i.e. "java instantiate class dinamically").

On the issue of the dynamic instantiation there are a lot of ClassLoader things that can be done but the most basic exemple is similar to the one you found... but there is a catch.

When you reference the A class on your code the jvm automatically loads it for you.
When you do

```
A a = (A)Class.forName("A").newInstance();
```

You will reference the A class you already have a grip of.

What you could do is create an interface that the classes you want to instantiate have to implement, like this:

```
String classPath = ...
AInterface a = (AInterface)Class.forName(classPath).newInstance();
```

And you use it from there.

But you have to remember to add the try-catch block, because the newInstance method will only know if the referenced class has a default constructor when it tries ti instantiate it at runtime, and if it doesn't have there will be an exception.

The same goes for a exception thrown by the contructor itself, it will be encapsulated and thrown back at you.

Comment: I'm not talking about `Class`, as it was given as an example. I wanted to know how experts of Java know about this in the first place, a time where they were once a novice in Java?

Comment: Actually, I should thank you for giving me more info about `Class`.

Comment: well I got excited talking about it :P I guess the secret is to always want to learn more... google is a nice friend too